# .html#id pages are not showing in Android Webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I am developing an app which has some webpages in asset folder. I am loading those webpages from asset folder to webview.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    WebView mWebView;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                    mWebView.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Problem is - every pages are loading except the pages like `kaidul.com/index.html#thisisproblem`. Rhis type of id oriented pages are not loading. Istead it is showing "requested page is not available". What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Actually this won't working in this way. I want to achieve an functionality which was of a phonegap app. And I am working in Android (Java) platform.